# Guzzle Client errror in status page and general slow performance

Tags: status, system-status

Not sure what is wrong, But when trying to see the status page in civicrm it takes a really long time to load and when it finally does it loads a guzzlehttp error.
the error is "Could not load a clean page to check"
The logs say the following 
```[error] Could not run checkCleanPage on https://www.example.com/civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=1. GuzzleHttp\Client returned cURL error 28: Failed to connect to www.example.com port 443 after 130561 ms: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)```

Comment: I just got this on Civi `5.63.1` after upgrading WordPress to `6.3.1`. It's not really clear where this is coming from.