# guzzle and symfony errors - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, composer, php8, symfony, guzzle

I've been getting a persistent guzzle error since Civi version 5.5x, and I now realise there's also some weird permission error and am wondering if this is related.

I'm on the latest versions of WordPress and CiviCRM, running PHP8.1 (though I only just upgraded PHP, hoping it would fix this - these errors appeared on PHP7.4). All extensions are up to date.

The Guzzle error appears in the system status console:

> **Guzzle client error**: Could not load a clean page to check

I have checked previous questions about guzzle. I upgraded to composer version 2 and ran `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:'^7'` but this has not resolved the problem.

I also noticed today an issue that may or may not be related. When I run `wp theme list` it throws a PHP error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.b16e0079d1aac6538c9e131b852f3532.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 87
Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.b16e0079d1aac6538c9e131b852f3532.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 87
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException: Cannot rename "/tmp/CachedCiviContainer.b16e0079d1aac6538c9e131b852f3532.phpa71jfv" to "/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedCiviContainer.b16e0079d1aac6538c9e131b852f3532.php". in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php:290
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php(696): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->rename()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php(124): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->dumpFile()
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php(84): Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCache->write()
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php(684): Civi\Core\Container->loadContainer()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php(87): Civi\Core\Container::boot()
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php(434): CRM_Core_Config::singleton()
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(972): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Admin->initialize()
#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(794): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->initialize()
#8 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(767): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_clean_urls()
#9 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(651): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_common()
#10 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks()
#11 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#12 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#13 /var/www/html/wp-settings.php(632): do_action()
#14 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1349): require('...')
#15 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1267): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#16 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#17 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(83): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#18 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(32): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#19 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(20): include('...')
#20 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#21 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 290
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException: Cannot rename "/tmp/CachedCiviContainer.b16e0079d1aac6538c9e131b852f3532.phpa71jfv" to "/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedCiviContainer.b16e0079d1aac6538c9e131b852f3532.php". in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php:290
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php(696): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->rename()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php(124): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->dumpFile()
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php(84): Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCache->write()
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php(684): Civi\Core\Container->loadContainer()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php(87): Civi\Core\Container::boot()
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php(434): CRM_Core_Config::singleton()
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(972): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Admin->initialize()
#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(794): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->initialize()
#8 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(767): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_clean_urls()
#9 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(651): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks_common()
#10 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->register_hooks()
#11 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#12 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#13 /var/www/html/wp-settings.php(632): do_action()
#14 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1349): require('...')
#15 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1267): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#16 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#17 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(83): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#18 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(32): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#19 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(20): include('...')
#20 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#21 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 290
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
```

This looks like a permissions error but as far as I can tell everything is correct: `www-data` owns everything, with `rw-r--r--` on all files and `rwxr-xr-x` on all directories in the path.

Any help with troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a plugin or CiviCRM extension using a newer version of the Guzzle package. I had a similar issue with LMS plugin so I replaced the guzzle package in CiviCRM with a newer version.

Comment: how do I know which extension and how to replace the package? I'm not clear what guzzle even does.

Comment: Basically I have exactly the same thing described here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43547/guzzle-client-errror-in-status-page-and-general-slow-performance

As far as I can tell the only things using guzzle are `civicrm` and `wp-rest` - I get this by running `grep -r Guzzle plugins/  | cut -f 3 -d '/' | sort | uniq`

Comment: Maybe Guzzle is in a theme?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on recent version of CiviCRM

```
No PSR-18 clients found. Make sure to install a package providing "psr/http-client-implementation". Example: "php-http/guzzle7-adapter".
```

Looking in the ext/ folder I get this result

```
[root@domain]# grep -r Guzzle  | cut -f 3 -d '/' | sort | uniq
composer
geocoder-php
intervention
php-http
phpunit
psr7": "Used with Guzzle PSR-7 Factories",
Ses
Uplang
Utils
```

Comment: Apparently reverting to v. 1.10 of Geocoder solves the issue. See https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.wikimedia.geocoder/issues/60